# How can I limit an onclick event to not work if the link has a certain class name?

Tags: jquery

I have the following JQuery:

```
                $("#content-button-panel")
                       .on('click', 'a', function (event) {
                           event.preventDefault();
                           var $link = $(this);
                           ServerFunctions.getContentAjax($link);
                       });
```

How can I make this work only when the links do not have a class of "folder"?

Answer (score 7):

```
 $("#content-button-panel")
                       .on('click', 'a:not(".folder")', function (event) {
                           event.preventDefault();
                           var $link = $(this);
                           ServerFunctions.getContentAjax($link);
                       });
```

- http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.hasClass` function as below;

```
                $("#content-button-panel")
                   .on('click', 'a', function (event) {
                       event.preventDefault();
                       if (!$(this).hasClass('folder'))
                       {
                          var $link = $(this);
                          ServerFunctions.getContentAjax($link);
                       }
                   });
```

Comment: Change `folder` to `'folder'`.